# Two way data binding using semantic ui searchable dropdown with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, semantic-ui

I am having an issue with Semantic-UI searchable dropdown and Vuejs data binding, at the moment it is only able to model bind 1 changed option regardless of the selected dropdown option. below is my code.

I tried using the @change event but this has brought no results for me.

```
           <select
              name="clients"
              id="clients"
              class="ui fluid search selection dropdown uppercase"
              v-model="selected_client"
            >
              <option value>Select Client</option>
              <option
                v-for="(client, index) in clients"
                :key="index"
                :value="client.services"
              >{{client.firstname}}, {{client.lastname}}</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Try `@input`. @Thomas Chirwa

Comment: Not working @mare96

Answer (score 0):

I realized my error, it was not on the @change event handler rather how I was handling the v-bind key as v-bind expect each key to be unique so in my case, I wasn't providing such so I passed the event to a method which filters out the specific client based on the id given as the value. below is the solution which worked for me.

I hope someone will find this useful.

```
       <select
          name="clients"
          id="clients"
          class="ui fluid search selection dropdown uppercase"
          @change="clientData($event)"
        >
          <option value>Select Client</option>
          <option
            v-for="client in clients"
            :key="client.id"
            :value="client.id"
          >{{client.firstname}}, {{client.lastname}}</option>
        </select>
```